# Get name/number of the table currently being edited

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

In MapInfo you can edit one table at a time.

**How can I programmatically get the name or ID number of the table that is currently being edited?**

I tried the following function:

```
Function GetEditableTable as String
  Dim i, j, WinID as integer
  Dim TableList() as String
  i = NumTables()
  ReDim TableList(i)

  WinID = FrontWindow()
  For j = 1 to i
    Note LayerInfo(WinID, j, LAYER_INFO_EDITABLE)
    If LayerInfo(WinID, j, LAYER_INFO_EDITABLE) = TRUE Then
      GetEditableTable = TableInfo(j, TAB_INFO_NAME)
      Exit Sub
    End If
  Next
End Function
```

...but it returns the same table name no matter which table is editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a function like this:

```
Function MAPGetEditLayerName(ByVal nMID As Integer) As String

Dim nEditLayerID As Integer

MAPGetEditLayerName = ""

    nEditLayerID    = MapperInfo(nMID, MAPPER_INFO_EDIT_LAYER)
    Do Case nEditLayerID
        Case -1
            '**No editable layer currently
        Case 0
            '**The cosmetic layer is currently editable
            MAPGetEditLayerName = LayerInfo(nMID, nEditLayerID, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
        Case Else
            MAPGetEditLayerName = LayerInfo(nMID, nEditLayerID, LAYER_INFO_NAME)
    End Case

End Function
```

One problem with your function is that you loop over the number of open tables and not the number of layers in the map.